# Run Two Laravel applications with docker on same server pointing to subdomain

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, devops

How do I run two Laravel Docker apps on the same server using one container per app and point to two domains?

Both apps are on the same AWS ec2 server

eg: 
container one points to -> one.mydomain.com
container two points to -> two.mydomain.com

I'm new to this.

Is it even possible?

an apache solution would be preferable.

Comment: Yes this is possible by using nginx proxy: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a possible and also different way to that and will suggest to use AWS services.

- Using AWS load balancer and [Host-based](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) routing and different port publish for each app
- Nginx

With AWS approach you need to run your container using ECS.

- Create Load balancer
- Create cluster
- Create service
- Attached service to Load balancer and update load balancer routing to Host-based routing `app1.example.com`, will route to `app1`

Repeat the above step for app2.

The above is the standard way to deal with the container using AWS.

You can read more about this [gentle-introduction-to-how-aws-ecs-works-with-example-tutorial](https://medium.com/boltops/gentle-introduction-to-how-aws-ecs-works-with-example-tutorial-cea3d27ce63d) and [Run containerized applications in production](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/)

With Nginx, you need to manage everything for your self.

- Run both containers on EC2
- Install Nginx
- Update Nginx configuration to route traffic based on DNS
- Update DNS Entry and will point to EC2 instance public IP, both DNS, for example, `app1.example.com` and `app2.example.com` will point to same EC2 instance but the Nginx will decide which app will serve the request.

```
server {
  server_name app1.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:HOSTPORT;
  }
}
server {
  server_name app2.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:HOSTPORT;
  }
}
```

I will recommend these two approaches, Nginx over apache but if you are interested you can check this [apache-vhosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html)